# How to access a api behind a proxy?

Tags: ajax, api, proxy, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy

I am trying to build a web application(on local host) that uses an API that is behind a proxy of my college.

For accessing the API on chrome web browser, I get a sign in page, where upon sign on, I get access to the data of the API.

When I query the API from my application by sending an ajax request. I get the login page in return. How do I access the API over a ajax request(at the same time authenticate the access)?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completion.

I figured a way to solve this was to use chromium for development. Chromium (with disabled security )allowed development of the webapp without any COR's issue.